# How to pass arguments to a function in "map" function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know a map function gets a function as its first argument and the next arguments are iterators on which the passed function needs to be applied. My question here is say if I have a 2d list like so

```
l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

how can I sort the individual lists in reverse order so my output is

```
l=[[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]]
```

I know a potential solution is using a lambda function such as

```
list(map(lambda x:x[::-1],l))
```

I want something like this

```
list(map(sorted, l,'reversed=True'))
```

where 'reversed=True' is an argument that sorted takes

eg:

```
>>> newList=[1,2,3]
>>> sorted(newList,reversed='True')
>>> [3,2,1]
```

I have seen how to pass arguments to a the pow function using the itertools.repeat module

```
map(pow,list,itertools.repeat(x))
```

x=power to which the list must be raised

I want to know if there is any way the arguments can be passed in a map function. In my case the 'reverse=True' for the sorted function.

Comment: Your solution using a lambda is, I believe, the one you should favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial` for this:

```py
import functools

new_list = list(map(functools.partial(sorted, reverse=True), l))
```

Comment: I was gonna post this because it is the way to go. But wrote the other option instead because you were first ;)

Comment: `functools.partial` is the python way for currying functions.

Comment: @TheNamesAlc Yes that's exactly how it works, you can read more from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `lambda` to wrap the funtion:

```
map(lambda x: sorted(x, reversed=True), l)
```

or:

```
map(lambda i, j: pow(i, j), list,itertools.repeat(x))
```

Comment: Which is what lambda allows you to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it.

You could use `functools.partial`. It creates a `partial`, for the lack of a better word, of the function you pass to it. It sort of creates a new function with some parameters already passed into it.

For your example, it would be:

```
from functools import partial
rev_sort = partial(sorted, reverse=True)
map(rev_sort, l)
```

The other way is using a simple lambda:

```
map(lambda arr: sorted(arr, reverse=True), l)
```

The other other way (my personal choice), is using generators:

```
(sorted(arr, reverse=True) for arr in l)
```

Comment: You are correct. 2 and 3 are technically the same. They are both lazily evaluated. The only difference is syntax, as far as I know. I prefer the third one because, for me, it is easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

For this specific case, you can also use a list comprehension -

`l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

`l = [list(reversed(sublist)) for sublist in l]`
//[[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]]